# Adding a Pinterest button to fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I've got fancybox installed for the image galleries on my site and I'm about to add the functionality of social media buttons (twitter and facebook) as outlined here http://jsfiddle.net/G5TC3/

```
$(".fancybox")
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({
    beforeShow: function () {
        if (this.title) {
            // New line
            this.title += '<br />';

            // Add tweet button
            this.title += '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none" data-url="' + this.href + '">Tweet</a> ';

            // Add FaceBook like button
            this.title += '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=' + this.href + '&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:110px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
        }
    },
    afterShow: function() {
        // Render tweet button
        twttr.widgets.load();
    },
    helpers : {
        title : {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    }  
});
```

I'd also like to add a 'pin it' button for pinterest - is there a way of extending this script to include pinterest?

Thanks

E

Comment: Just added this script and the facebook share button appears, but I don't get the twitter one - it just appears as the word 'Tweet'

Comment: I used the shareThis script instead (you could choose what social media buttons to add) Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/12943117/1055987 includes demo.

Comment: Wow JFK that looks really good - not sure I understand it all, but off to read the documentation and give implementation a go - thanks for sharing - hopefully I can get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Your Twitter button is rendering correctly for me, but from your given source, it appears as though you've unnecessarily linked to Twitter's `widget.js`.  Just add the following to the end of your `<body>`.

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

As for Pintrest, just load their script with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

Building the link is a bit harder.  This is the basic structure:

```
<a data-pin-config="above" href="//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=pageUrl&media=imgUrl&description=myDescription" data-pin-do="buttonPin" >
  <img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png" />
</a>
```

So you can either load the `href` dynamically, or hard code it in yourself.

Comment: Hi there - thanks for the reply - I've just copied the script directly from the fancybox site example so no idea why the twitter button isn't rendering for me as it does fine in their example - will try your code snippet and add it - does it go before the end body tag </body>?

Comment: As for pinterest - not sure I can just slip an <a></a> tag into the script like that - surely I need to code it like the other two buttons? I don't write jquery or javascript and so wouldn't know where to start. I'd want the pin it button to site next to the twitter and facebook buttons and by dynamically generated for each image - I have so many images that I don't want to sit and hardcode it in for each.

Comment: As suggested, place `this.title += '<a href="//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=pageUrl&media=imgUrl&description=myDescription" data-pin-config="above" data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-url="' + this.href + '"><img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png" /></a> ';` at the top, and `<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>` just before the `</body>` tag in your document.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful to you: http://jsfiddle.net/BK6h4/

Don't forget to add a Jquery (maybe 1.8.3) to the header of your page.

```
$(".fancy")
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({
    beforeShow: function () {
        if (this.title) {
            // New line
            this.title += '<br />';

            // Add tweet button
            this.title += '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none" data-url="' + this.href + '">Tweet</a> ';

            // Add Pinterest button
            this.title += '<a href="//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=pageUrl&media=imgUrl&description=myDescription" data-pin-config="above"  data-pin-do="buttonPin" data-url="' + this.href + '"><img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png" /></a> ';


            // Add FaceBook like button
            this.title += '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=' + this.href + '&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:110px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
        }
    },
    afterShow: function() {
        // Render tweet button
        twttr.widgets.load();
    },
    helpers : {
        title : {
        titlePosition       : 'inside',

        }
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, all you need to do is add the pin it button to the title just like you added the others.  There is a full outline of how to do this here: http://scottgale.com/using-pinterest-with-fancybox/2012/08/15/

Looking at your script, all you need to do is add it in where you are doing the title modifications in your script:

```
//add pinterest button for title
this.title += '<a href="<a class="vglnk" title="Link added by VigLink" rel="nofollow" href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url='+"><span>http</span><span>://</span><span>pinterest</span><span>.</span><span>com</span><span>/</span><span>pin</span><span>/</span><span>create</span><span>/</span><span>button</span><span>/?</span><span>url</span><span>='+</span></a>
    encodeURIComponent(document.location.href)+
    '&media=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.homesburlingtonvermont.com'+
    encodeURIComponent(this.href)+
    '&description=Pin from <a class="vglnk" title="Link added by VigLink" rel="nofollow" href="http://ScottGale.com"><span>ScottGale</span><span>.</span><span>com</span></a>" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal">'+
    '<img border="0" src="<a class="vglnk" title="Link added by VigLink" rel="nofollow" href="http://assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png"><span>http</span><span>://</span><span>assets</span><span>.</span><span>pinterest</span><span>.</span><span>com</span><span>/</span><span>images</span><span>/</span><span>PinExt</span><span>.</span><span>png</span></a>" title="Pin It" /></a>';
```