# Sharing images on social media without displaying the full image path

Tags: jquery, attr, social-media

I am using the solution posted on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12923229/sharethis-plugin-not-working-in-fancybox-title/12943117?noredirect=1#comment25182497_12943117) as shown [here](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/shareThisInTitle_17oct12.html). I am trying to get social media buttons to work on fancybox with the thumbnail helper.

The buttons are appearing just fine. My question is, when I go to share an image on, say, Facebook, the full path to the image is shown:

[image]

I'd like to instead see the title of the image with the domain displayed underneath:

[image]

My jQuery:

```
function buildShareBtns(url){
         var customShareBtns  = "<div class='share'>"; // class for styling maybe
             customShareBtns += "<a href='mailto:?subject=Shared from Tacoma Weekly:"+url+"'><img src='/assets/v4/images/email32.png' /></a>";
             customShareBtns += "<a href='http://twitter.com/share?url="+url+"'><img src='/assets/v4/images/twitter32.png' /></a>";
             customShareBtns += "<a href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="+url+"'><img src='/assets/v4/images/facebook32.png' /></a>";
             customShareBtns += "</div>";
             return customShareBtns;
    }
```

Is there a way to extract the title attribute from the `url` parameter so that this can happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered making a facebook ["application"](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) and then using their dialog API?

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
```

The URLs are a little longer, and it's definitely a little bit more work, but it allows you to customise the sharing dialog much more effectively.

It's really well explained with lots of good info on the [Facebook tutorial for this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. This is for work, though, so I don't have too much leeway.

Comment: Should work for you anyway.. check out the `URL Redirection` section.. it's just a URL, like the one you already have!