# Fancybox pinterest button - how to pass link title to pin description?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I found this question how to add pinterest hover button to FancyBox2
[fancbybox pinterest jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554329/fancbybox-pinterest-jquery)
which works great, I just couldn't solve how to add description to the pin?

```
var pinUrl = a.attr('href') + '?url='+ encodeURIComponent(location.href) 
                    + '&media='+ encodeURIComponent(img.attr('src'))
                    + '&description=' (what goes here??);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with the API, but to appropriately add a `description` parameter and keep it encoded, you would do:

```
var pinUrl = a.attr('href') + '?url='+ encodeURIComponent(location.href) 
                + '&media='+ encodeURIComponent(img.attr('src'))
                + '&description=' + encodeURI('I am some string of text');
```

Abstracting this:

```
function pinUrl(link, img, description) {
    return link.attr('href') + '?url=' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href) + '&media=' + encodeURIComponent(img.attr('src')) + '&description=' + encodeURI(description);
}
```

// Usage:

```
var myPinUrl = pinURL($("#somelink"), $("#someimage"), "Look at this cool text!");
```

// EDITED:
If you have a set of links with variable information, you might use the pinUrl function like so:

```
var pin_url_list = [];

$("#mydiv a").each(function() {
    pin_url_list.push( pinUrl( $(this), $(this).find("img.featured"), $(this).attr("title") );
});
```

Comment: The title is different for each image:
<a class="fancybox" href="image_t.jpg" title="ImageTitle"><img class="imgg" src="image.jpg" alt="" /></a>

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

You could get the description from the `title` attribute of your link (or use a `data-caption` attribute) like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers: {
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    },
    beforeShow: function () {
        this.title = this.title ?
            '<div class="myPint" style="height: 26px"><a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.href) +
            '&media=' + encodeURIComponent(this.href) +
            '&description=' + this.title + '" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal">' +
            '<img border="0" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" align="absmiddle"/></a>' +
            '<span> ' + this.title + '</span></div>' 
        :
            '<div class="myPint" style="height: 26px"><a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.href) +
            '&media=' + encodeURIComponent(this.href) +
            '&description='+$(this.element).data("caption")+'" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal">' +
            '<img border="0" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" title="Pin It" /></a>' +
            '<span>&nbsp;</span></div>'
    }
});
```

**<kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n73pq/)</kbd>**

Comment: Thank you, but this way of adding pin it button is not using `beforShow` and it is not in the fancybox title. When I use `$(this.element).data("caption")` in the code from this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554329/fancbybox-pinterest-jquery for description, it says "null" even if data-caption is at each link.

Comment: @Katka : this is an alternative solution that works! I am not reproducing/mimicking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554329/fancbybox-pinterest-jquery  ...  but yes, I may have wrongly assumed that you would understand that using a data-caption requires you to set the `data-caption` in your link (my bad). It works with `title` though.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your help, I just wanted the button to be in the picture, not in the title (title is outside image).

Comment: is it please possible to make your version of pinterest button to open in a new window (with set up width and height)? Thank you