# Addthis - Not showing buttons/images when loading with jquery

Tags: jquery, fancybox, addthis

I'm using fancybox to display images and i would like to show social network buttons under the image. However i am having some issues with addthis, the buttons aren't showing, they are just plain links even if i render addthis again.

Javascript:

```
 beforeShow: function () {
                        if (this.title) {
                            // New line

                            this.title += '<br />';


                            //addThis
                            this.title += '<div id="toolbox" class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style"></div>';


                        }
                    }, afterShow: function () {

                        var tbx = document.getElementById("toolbox"),
                            svcs = {email: 'Email', print: 'Print', facebook: 'Facebook', expanded: 'More'};

                        for (var s in svcs) {
                            tbx.innerHTML += '<a class="addthis_button_'+s+'">'+svcs[s]+'</a>';
                        }



                        //addthis.init();
                        //addthis.toolbox('#toolbox');
                        //addthis.button('.addthis_button');
                        addthis.toolbox("#toolbox");
//addthis.button(".addthis_button_email");

    },
```

Result: [image: HTML Outcome of addthis]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you married to addthis? otherwise you may want to try sharethis http://stackoverflow.com/a/12943117/1055987 (includes demo ;)

Comment: Judging by your screenshot it looks like AddThis is attempting to render the buttons. If it weren't then the text in the buttons would just be the service names, which is what your code outputs.

So the question is: Why isn't the CSS being obeyed? Do you have an example page where I could see this in action?

Comment: @JFK Thanks for the suggestion, i switched to sharethis and it worked immediatly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to sharethis fixed my problem.