# Adding Pinterest Button to Fancybox 2.0 to already existing Jquery doc

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox-2, pinterest

I am fairly familiar with html and css, new-ish with php but more than a bit new with jquery.

I am trying to add Pinterest Button inside the images in a fancybox (2.0.5) for our company wordpress site, MercuryMosaics.com (WP site)
(like on http://scottgale.com/blogsamples/fancybox-pinterest/index.html )

The issue is there's an existing jquery for fancybox. I am not entirely sure where to edit/place what code in order to implement a pinterest button in the fancybox popups (like on Scott Gale example above.)

My existing code is in
http://www.mercurymosaics.com/wp-content/themes/MercuryMosaics/library/js/ 
under "jquery.fancybox.pack.js"

I've inspected the jquery doc for the above scott gale page, but no more certainty on implementing it.

Any help? Thanks :)

PS - an example of pages it would appear on navigate to any of the specific product or gallery pages on site above

Comment: I used the ShareThis plugin for most social buttons (including pinterest) in this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/12943117/1055987 if that helps (includes demo)

Comment: So the working demo from link you sent is here http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/shareThisInTitle_17oct12.html, (i can pull up the js to add) but i am not entirely sure how to add this the existing js I have: http://www.mercurymosaics.com/wp-content/themes/MercuryMosaics/library/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js Any help?

Comment: Did you check the source code of the demo? that has the script you need .... and you don't need to add it to the fancybox js file you have by the way.

Comment: Yes, I can see the source code easy enough - just not sure where to add it then I guess - thought I had to add to existing fancybox js